# custom post type template returns wrong permalink in loop

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

I created a custom post type(employee bio) and a custom template to display excerpts, attached images, and get the permalink to link to the custom post type.

When I use my custom template to loop through my custom post type it gets the attached image and the excerpt, but when i use `get_permalink()` in the loop it returns the permalink of the page the template is used on rather than the permalink of each post it's looping through, I exhausted so I'm probably overlooking something.

custom post type (functions.php)

```
add_action('init', 'employee_bio',1);

     function employee_bio() {
       $feature_args = array(
          'labels' => array(
           'name' => __( 'Employee Bios' ),
           'singular_name' => __( 'Employee Bio' ),
           'add_new' => __( 'Add New Bio' ),
           'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Bio' ),
           'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Bio' ),
           'new_item' => __( 'New Bio' ),
           'view_item' => __( 'View Bio' ),
           'search_items' => __( 'Search Employee Bios' ),
           'not_found' => __( 'No Employee Bio found' ),
           'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Employee Bio found in trash' )
         ),
       'public' => true,
       'show_ui' => true,
       'capability_type' => 'page',
       'hierarchical' => true,
    'has_archive' => false,
    'can_export' => true,
       'rewrite' => array('pages' => true, 'with_front' => false),
       'menu_position' => 20,
       'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail','excerpt', 'page-attributes','post-formats' )
     );
  register_post_type('bio',$feature_args);
}
```

custom template (bio_overview.php )

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'bio') ); ?>
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="contentwide" class="site-content" role="main">

            <?php while ($loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

                <div class="bio_summeries">

                    <div class="mini_headshot">
                        <?php echo the_post_thumbnail('full');?>
                    </div>

                    <p class="bio_excerpt">
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
                    </p>
                    <a href="".<?php get_permalink();?> .""> Read More > </a>
                    <!--<div class="read_more_bio"></div>-->

                </div>

                <?php //comments_template( '', true ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        </div><!-- #content .site-content -->
    </div><!-- #primary .content-area -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, i had to remove the extra quotes and concatenation from the `<a>` tag and `echo` the result. So: `<a href="".<?php get_permalink();?> .""> Read More > </a>`  becomes:  `<a href="<?php echo get_permalink();?>"> Read More > </a>`

Which got it working. Now, time to get some sleep.